Multiple devops agent in azure container apps
I'm using containerized self hosted Azure Devops agent in Azure container apps. This is working fine. Now, I want to create multiple agents with different tech stack. I have those images created and hosted in ACR. Now, should I create multiple azure container jobs in same azure container environment or use multiple containers in one same azure container job?
Also, how would my pipeline know which container job should run based on application tech stack?

"should I create multiple jobs in same environment or use multiple containers in one same job?" - this is a bit confusing, could you please elaborate? You mean agent pool instead of environment? FYI one pipeline job will be run by one and only one build agent.

Sorry about any confusions. I have updated my post. By environment I meant azure container environment which contains my container job with container running devops agent. HTH

For deploying multiple Azure DevOps agents with different tech stacks, you have two options
Multiple Azure Container Apps Jobs in the Same Azure Container Environment. This approach keeps each agent isolated in its own job, allowing more control over scaling and resource allocation per tech stack.
Multiple Containers in a Single Azure Container App Job which is little complicated but technically possible. Using multiple containers in a single job could lead to resource contention and complexity in managing different images.
So I would recommend option 1 i.e. Create multiple container apps jobs for each agent in the same container env
assuming your acr, agent image and container apps env is ready


example-
Create your agent job example .NET agent job
az containerapp job create --name dotnet-agent-job --resource-group arkorg --environment arkoContainerEnv --image arkoacr.azurecr.io/dotnet-agent:v1 --cpu 0.5 --memory 1.0Gi --registry-identity system --registry-server arkoacr.azurecr.io --tags stack=dotnet --trigger-type manual

Since this is for DevOps agent jobs that need to start on demand, I am using manual trigger, based on your scenario / requirement you can modify it to event or schedule as well.

Same way, you create for other Node.js / python / etc agent jobs
To ensure your pipeline runs on the correct container (agent), you can add tags to agents based on the tech stack (e.g dotnet, nodejs, python, etc)
So for dotnet or nodejs your tags should look like this
trigger:
  - main

jobs:
  - job: DotNetJob
    displayName: Build with .NET Agent
    pool:
      name: Default
      demands:
        - stack -equals dotnet
    steps:
      - script: |
          echo "Building .NET Application"
          dotnet build MyApp.sln
        displayName: 'Build .NET App'

  - job: NodeJsJob
    displayName: Build with Node.js Agent
    pool:
      name: Default
      demands:
        - stack -equals nodejs
    steps:
      - script: |
          echo "Building Node.js Application"
          npm install
          npm run build
        displayName: 'Build Node.js App'

For further clarity check out pool.demands definition | Microsoft Learn , SO thread and Configure demands - Managed DevOps Pools Preview | Microsoft Learn

I tried to follow the same steps however my pipeline failed with error stating "no agent found in pool Default which satisfies the specified demands: stack -equals dotnet, agent.version -gtversion 2.163.1"

Can you check pipeline version ? greater than 2.163.1 and  can you check the agent availability in the pool i.e .NET and Node.js agents are listed as connected? because your error message is saying it needs a higher version.

My placeholder agent version is 3.246.0. I can't see any other agents when I run pipeline. Nothing in job execution history. However, if I remove demands from pipeline then the agent shows up in pool. But at that time I'm not certain which agent picks up the job.

For anyone interested, got it working with the help of demands in
https://keda.sh/docs/2.15/scalers/azure-pipelines/ and environment variables.
